# express-jwt secret does not import process.env.JWT_SECRET

Tags: node.js, express, express-jwt

I'm trying to use `process.env.JWT_SECRET` for the secret but it just trow error:

```
export const requireSignin = expressjwt({
  secret: `${process.env.JWT_SECRET}`,
  algorithms: ["HS256"],
  userProperty: "auth",
});
```

This way I don't have error but the then I get 'UnauthorizedError: invalid signature'

```
export const requireSignin = expressjwt({
  secret: process.env.JWT_SECRET,
  algorithms: ["HS256"],
  userProperty: "auth",
});
```

This way I get "RangeError: express-jwt: `secret` is a required option"

```
export const requireSignin = () =>{

  return expressjwt({
  secret: process.env.JWT_SECRET,
  algorithms: ["HS256"], 
  userProperty: "auth",
  }); 
}
```

This way just load forever.

```
export const requireSignin = expressjwt({
  secret: '09f26e402586e2faa8da4c98a35f1b20d6b033c6097befa8be3486a829587fe2f90a832bd3ff9d42710a4da095a2ce285b009f0c3730cd9b8e1af3eb84df6611',
  algorithms: ["HS256"],
  userProperty: "auth",
});
```

And here is the only way working (which is problematic..)
Any help is welcome, thank you.

Comment: Make sure that you invalidate / change your secret given that you've exposed it here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1 - Install `dotenv`

2 - Require it where you need the env variable:

```
require("dotenv/config");
```

Comment: Already done...

Comment: You were right, forgot to use 'dotenv.config()'

Answer (score 1):

You can try

`npm install dotenv`

And add this on top of `server.js`file :

```
require('dotenv').config()
```

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest to use the following package
[nmicro-router](https://www.npmjs.com/package/nmicro-router)

Example for configuring JWT validation

```
import express  from 'express'
import { JWTAuth } from 'nmicro-jwt-auth' 
import {Router} from  'nmicro-router'

const JWT_VALIDATION_SECRET = process.env.JWT_SECRET 
const myRouter = new Router(express.Router())
myRouter.authHandler.setAdapter(new JWTAuth())  

const app = express()
app.use(express.json())
app.use(myRouter.router)

const myFn = (req, res) =>  res.send(`Hurray! It is working`) 

const options = { auth: true }
myRouter.post('/test', myFn, options)

const port = 8081
app.listen(port, () => console.log(`App listening in port ${port}`))
```